# How to mock components with jest and keep component name

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I need to mock some components. I do it like this:

`jest.mock('widgets/Link', () => () => 'Link');`

However when I do it like this, component name is lost in all snapshots. I get:

```
-           <Link
+           <Component
```

When I go with (which I guess is wrong, cos mock function should return component, not string):

`jest.mock('widgets/Link', () => 'Link');`

Then component name in snapshots is preserved, however I get other React warnings like:

> Warning:  is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

How can I correctly mock a component and preserve its name?